# Eclipse debug.keystore signing error for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created a keystore certificate using the platform certificate.

I used the following way to create a debug keystore:-

```
keytool-importkeypair -k ~/.android/debug.keystore -p android -pk8 platform.pk8 -cert platform.x509.pem -alias platform
```

Now to use this keystore in eclipse to debug the application, I replaced the default keystore in "Documents and Settings\raj.android\" with the new one I created.
Now when I try to debug any application, eclipse says that:

> "Error generating final archive: Unable to get debug signature key"

I tried restarting the eclipse, change the JRE to 1.5, but non worked.

Regards,
Raj

Comment: give the full path here /.android/debug.keystore this will work for linux.

Answer (score 3):

I got this solved.
The password provided for creating the certificate was incorrect. The password "platform" is valid if it is used to devices.
To use emulator for debuigging the application on emulator, the password should be "androiddebugkey"

Hence the command to generate the certificate will be:-

```
keytool-importkeypair -k ~/.android/debug.keystore -p android -pk8 platform.pk8 -cert platform.x509.pem -alias androiddebugkey
```

Thanks for the help.